# Counting loop returns 1 instead of actual count

Tags: ruby, for-loop

I need to count different letters in two similar strings.

Here is my code:

```
class Hamming
  def compute(dna1, dna2)
    count=0
    for i in 0...dna1.length
      count=+1 unless dna1[i] == dna2[i]            
    end     
    return count    
  end
end

ham = Hamming.new
ham.compute('ABBCCDD', 'AABBCCD')
#=> 1
```

My method keeps returning `1` if there is a match or `0` if there is none.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for not speaking English like a native. We'll ask questions if we didn't understand your question, and/or someone will eventually come along and clean it up to be more understandable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you're actually trying to compute hamming distance of long strings, you would be better served by an existing library that uses a native extension. And if you're really working on DNA sequencing and comparison, I'd strongly recommend utilizing some of the existing open source tools like [gatk](https://www.broadinstitute.org/gatk/) and [tophat](http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/tophat/index.shtml), or commercial solutions like [bina](http://www.bina.com/).

Comment: I'm just learning Ruby, and this was an example, but Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should write `count+=1` (incrementing count) instead of `count=+1` (assigning +1 to count)

Comment: Damn, didn't see that one :)

Comment: Oh, so they are different, I didn't know that, Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to meditate on:

```
foo = 'ABBCCDD'
bar = 'AABBCCD'
differences = foo.chars.zip(bar.chars).reject{ |x,y| x == y } # => [["B", "A"], ["C", "B"], ["D", "C"]]
differences.size # => 3
```

Comment: ..or `.count { |a,b| a != b }` in place of `.reject...`.

Comment: Ha! A [couple of hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127404/comparing-a-string-with-an-array-of-strings-and-printing-the-count/26127444#26127444) I forgot that `count` didn't have to take a block.