# Comparing a string with an array of strings and printing the count

Tags: ruby

I'm comparing a string to an array of strings using:

```
arry.include? (mystring)
```

and it returns a boolean value. How can I print out how many strings in that array equaled to mystring?

Comment: First step is to Google "ruby array".  Read the methods, and see if any meet your needs.

Comment: Hello Dorian, If you liked my answer, Please accept it. It will help me fetching more points ....:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array.count(mystring)

["Cat", "Dog", "Cat"].count("Cat") #=> 2

["Cat", "Dog", "Cat"].count("Dog") #=> 1
```

Comment: Best answer (+1), but your presentation could be improved, starting with `arry.count(mystring)`.

Comment: The solution is good, but the example is bad. You don't need that many irrelevant elements in the array. You should rather include elements like `"Catwoman"` to show that it is not doing a regex match or a partial match.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I am new to Stack Overflow. Will surely try to improve my representation of answer

Comment: See that "edit" button?  It's there for a reason.  You can edit, as long as you do not change the essence of your answer. You can also add most anything as long as you identify it as an edit (e.g., "Edit:..."). Here, I don't think you need to identify it as an edit. First give your answer (`arry.count(mystring)`), then your examples, being mindful of @sawa's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
arry.count { |s| s == mystring }
```

assuming `mystring` is a variable holding a string.  If it's meant to be a literal, you want `s == "mystring"`.

Edit: @kapiltekwani's answer is clearly better. I forgot about that form of `count`.